# Syntax highlighting in emails?

Tags: mail.app, development, text, formatting

I'd like Mail to pick up on syntax

I'm copying mostly from an app that does highlight syntax, but it doesn't seem to apply any sort of "formatting" to the text itself on pasting (e.g. color, font, size, etc.)

For code, I mostly send MySQL queries in emails

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though I was really looking for a way to copy from say TextMate into an email and preserve highlighting...

Since there are no answers, I found this answer as a decent workaround somewhere so I thought I'd share:

Head to an online syntax highlighting tool like [tohtml.com](http://tohtml.com) and then copy and paste the text into your email

Fairly quick and easy to use :)